# Boost C++ XML parsing

Tags: c++, xml, boost, tree

I am slightly familiar on how to parse XML with boost, if the XML has up to and including 3 levels. However, I am having trouble with the following example:

(Please ignore the slight lack of logic in the XML since this is an adaptation of something I cannot change. The structure is important)

```
<content>

      <Room>
           <RoomName>Livingroom</RoomName>             
            <Description> 
                 <Color>Red</Color>
                 <Size>Small</Size>                   
            </Description>
            <Description>
                 <Color>Blue</Color>
                 <Size>Big</Size>                         
            </Description>         
      </Room>

      <Room>
           <RoomName>Bathroom</RoomName>
            <Description>
                <Color>Green</Color>
                <Size>Medium</Size>
            </Description>
      </Room>  

</content>
```

I have tried this:

```
struct Room
{
    std::string roomName;
    std::string  roomColor;
    std::string  roomSize;   
};

void parseRoomsXml(){

    boost::property_tree::ptree tree;
    boost::property_tree::read_xml("./Rooms.xml", tree);
    boost::property_tree::ptree formats = tree.get_child("content");

    BOOST_FOREACH( boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type const& f, formats ) {
        if( f.first == "Room" ) {
            Room s;
            s.roomName = f.second.get<std::string>("RoomName");
            std::cout<<s.roomName<<std::endl;

            const boost::property_tree::ptree & attributes = formats.get_child("Room");

            BOOST_FOREACH( boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type const& v, attributes ) {
                if (v.first == "Description"){
                    s.roomColor = v.second.get<std::string>("Color");
                    s.roomSize = v.second.get<std::string>("Size");
                    std::cout<< s.roomColor << " " <<s.roomSize;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Result is that the first room is parsed correctly, but the second room has the Description of the first one:

=========================

Output:

Livingroom

Red   Small

Blue  Big

Bathroom

Red   Small

Blue  Big

========================

Expected result would be:

Livingroom

Red   Small

Blue  Big

Bathroom

Green Medium

===================================

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated, since I am trying to get used to boost.

Comment: The problem seems to be in this statement: const boost::property_tree::ptree & attributes = formats.get_child("Room"); it gets the first child each time..

Comment: It is, by I don't know how to manipulate it to loop over them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in this statement: const boost::property_tree::ptree & attributes = formats.get_child("Room");

You can iterate over the children using the following code:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &v,
    config.get_child("path.to.array_of_objects"))
{
    std::cout << "First data: " << v.first.data() << std::endl;
    boost::property_tree::ptree subtree = (boost::property_tree::ptree) v.second ;
    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &vs,
        subtree)
    {
        std::cout << "Sub data: " << vs.first.data() << std::endl;
        color = vs.second.get<std::string>("Color");
        roomSize = vs.second.get<std::string>("Size");
    }
}
```

Comment: With this implementation, the Sub data returned is "Description". My problem is getting one level deeper, to fetch the actual "Color" and "Size". Of course, if I use vs.second.data(), nothing is returned/displayed. This is why I was trying to get the child of the child, so I can access that last level.

Comment: works with an extra condition before getting the color and the roomSize, to check that vs.first.data == "Description"

Answer (score 1):

This code is working fine for me

```
boost::property_tree::ptree formats = tree.get_child("content");
BOOST_FOREACH( boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type const& f, formats ) {
if( f.first == "Room" ) {
   Room s;
   s.roomName = f.second.get<std::string>("RoomName");
   boost::property_tree::ptree subtree2 = (boost::property_tree::ptree) f.second ;
   std::cout<<s.roomName<<std::endl;
   BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &v,
           subtree2)
   {

       if(v.first == "Description"){
           s.roomColor = v.second.get<std::string>("Color");
           s.roomSize = v.second.get<std::string>("Size");
           std::cout<< s.roomColor << std::endl<<s.roomSize<<std::endl;

           }
       }
     }
}
```